# How to stop the view controller reloading the data each time it is visited?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a table of data and also a map that loads the data with annotations.

I would like to have the data only load first time the user visits the view and then only reload if they call a method via an update button. At the moment the view reloads the data each visit. I'm calling the `requestData` for the `UITableView` and a `load map`method I have in the `viewDidLoad` method.

I'm sending the user to the view with the following code. Perhaps it forces the viewDidLoad method each time:

```
-(IBAction)pushHomeButton{

// front view controller

[self.homeBtn setTitleColor:customColorGrey forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0001 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    FrontViewController *myNewUIViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myNewUIViewController];
    [self.revealController setFrontViewController:myNavController];
    // Putting back the front view on focus
    [self.revealController showViewController:self.revealController.frontViewController];

});
```

}

thanks for any help.

Comment: So create an instance (flag) variable.

Comment: are you moving away from that view to other views, and dont want it to load again . ?

Comment: write code in `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillApear`

Comment: yes. the user can switch views and then return to this view. my methods are in viewDidLoad and not in viewWillAppear - that's why I don't understand why they are reloading the data each time. I suppose the view is loading on each visit.

Comment: Is the issue around the time it takes, for example, to request and download a new map?

Comment: I added some code showing how I send the user to the view each time. maybe the way I'm doing it calls the viewDidLoad each time because of the alloc and init. not sure how to change it though...

Comment: Here is a cue from apple's doc. UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews method of UIView so that it calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of UITableView or when you assign a new data source.

Comment: @user2588945 You have tried my way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can load th data just in the `viewDidLoad` a then you make variable in `NSUserDefaults`

You set this when the app is load:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"FirstTime"];
```

and then when you are in the viewDidLoad of your Controller

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstTime"]) {

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"FirstTime"];

            //Code for load data


        }
```

Comment: Why does `NSUserDefaults` need to be involved?  What's wrong with an (static) variable?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it looks like you're storing data into the View Controller instance (you said you're loading it in the `viewDidLoad` method).

What you seem to want is the data to be cached once it's loaded. You can do this several ways, the simplest of which would be to store it in a global context, such as the AppDelegate instance; inside the `viewDidLoad` method in your view controller, you would test if the data is already there and hasn't expired, in which case you'll skip the resource load and use it instead. Otherwise, you would load the data and store it in that AppDelegate property.

Comment: Or a static variable, private to the class?